# How to dial a number out without chooser popup in directly in andorid 6.0

Tags: java, android, xml, string, dialog

I am trying to dial a phone number out in android 6.0. I can dial a phone number out using marshmallow permission. but when I tap on the dial button, chooser dialog popup for selecting whether dial app or skype app.

So I added a code "intent.setPackage'com.android.phone'", app worked well in android 5.x , but unfortunately app crashed in android 6.0.

How to dial a number out without chooser popup in directly in android 6.0

Answer (score 0):

You can see permission code here.

```
 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(AppointmentDetailActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AppointmentDetailActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);
        }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks 
I added already this permission.
And this code is working well in android 6.0

  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
  intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
  activity.startActivity(intent, true);

This code make chooser popup to launch with skype app.

So I changed a little like below.

 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
  intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
 intent.setPackage("com.android.phone")
  activity.startActivity(intent, true);

But app crashed in android 6.0.

Comment: Paste your crash log.

Comment: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx pkg=com.android.phone }

Comment: Write this permission in manifest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />?